# How to show dock on all monitors in Catalina?

Tags: macos, display, dock

I have my dock on the right side of the screen, but it only appears on my designated primary display. How can I have it so that it displays on all screens instead? Nothing I've seen online seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn’t how the dock works. Apple puts it on one screen only.

You can do some setting with mission control and hiding, so you might be happy with that.

- [How to get a dock on multiple monitors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157402/how-to-get-a-dock-on-multiple-monitors)
- [Is it possible to have my dock visible on all monitors in El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213251/is-it-possible-to-have-my-dock-visible-on-all-monitors-in-el-capitan)
- [show dock permanently on the primary display only or simultaneously on both displays](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369771/show-dock-permanently-on-the-primary-display-only-or-simultaneously-on-both-disp)

You could use a third party app to make a launcher window on multiple screens or move to using a keyboard based launcher like LaunchBar or Alfred.

Comment: That's a shame. But alright, thank you for your help!

Comment: If I didn’t love LaunchBar and use it to see what apps are running by keyboard and didn’t hide my dock all the time, I would want what you ask for, too initially. Especially on massive displays docks can be very useful for status and minimizing mouse travel time. @CesarPerez

Comment: Yea.  Macs cost more and aren't as good as Linux.  What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: overpriced laptops with so many missing features! Not to mention the crappy keyboard

Comment: This is stupid. A multi monitor setup means relegating secondary things to the non-central monitor. The dock shouldn't be forcibly relegated like that.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I use my MacBook via thunderbolt 3 dock, 4k display, mouse and keyboard.

when I find myself doing the kind of work where I need to refer to one screen while manipulating another screen, I push the keyboard aside and open up the MacBook.

I've discovered this app that, more or less, mimics the dock on the Macbook's Touch Bar:

https://pock.dev/lack/

it is not perfect, but rather than choose a single display, I can quickly switch apps with a single tap without moving my hands.

not perfect, but it is what I am using until I can have 'dock left/auto-hide' on two displays oriented vertically.

You can have a bottom dock on both displays, but the bottom is the absolute worst place to have the dock.